# Master detail relation, Variables & XML in OpenERP 7

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp-7

I am trying to create a Product Specification Module in OpenERP 7. Some work already done. But confused with Master-detail relation, Variables & XML.

Take a look at this picture

[image]

Need to create this lower part form this .py & .xml file.

product_pspec.py

```
from openerp.osv import osv, fields

class product_pspec(osv.osv):

  _name = "product.pspec"

  _columns = {
    'prototype': fields.char('Prototype#', size=20),
    'style': fields.char('Style#', size=20),
    'customer': fields.char('Customer', size=20),
    'body_type': fields.char('Body Type', size=20),
    'program_brand': fields.char('Program/Brand', size=20),
    'color_asstmnt': fields.char('Color Asstmnt', size=200),
    'size_info': fields.integer('Size Info', size=20),
    'description': fields.char('Description', size=500),
    'designer': fields.char('Designer', size=20),
    'factory': fields.char('factory', size=20),
    'pcs_hanger': fields.integer('Pcs/Hanger', size=20),
    'developed_sold': fields.char('Developed/Sold', size=20),

  }


class product_pspec_details(osv.osv):

  _name = "product.pspec.details"

  _columns = {
       'product_pspec_id' : fields.many2one('product.pspec', 'Product Pspec', required=True),
       'product_product_id' : fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product Product', required=True),
       'supplier_name': fields.char('Supplier Name', size=20),
       'style_number': fields.char('Style Number', size=20),
       'where_used': fields.char('Where Used', size=20),
       'est_yield': fields.char('Est. Yield', size=20),
       'price': fields.char('Price', size=20),
       'cost_dz': fields.char('Cost Dz', size=20),
  }
  _sql_constraints = [
        ('uniq_name', 'unique(product_product_id, supplier_name, where_used)', "Already Added"),
  ]

product_pspec()
product_pspec_details()
```

product_pspec.py.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="product_pspec_product">
<field name="name">product.pspec</field>
<field name="model">product.pspec</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
  <form string="Create product Specification" version="7.0">
    <group>
    <field name="prototype"/>
    <field name="style"/>
    <field name="customer"/>
    <field name="body_type"/>
    <field name="program_brand"/>
    <field name="color_asstmnt"/>
    <field name="size_info"/>
    <field name="description"/>
    <field name="designer"/>
    <field name="factory"/>
    <field name="pcs_hanger"/>
    <field name="developed_sold"/>
    <field colspan="4" name="product_pspec_id" widget="many2one_list">
        <tree string="Materials" editable="bottom">
     <field name="product_product_id"/>
     <field name="Supplier Name"/>
     <field name="Style number"/>
     <field name="Where Used"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
    </group>
   </form>
</field>
</record>
<record id="product_specification_product_act_window" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Product Specification</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">product.pspec</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="product_pspec_product"/>
</record>
 <menuitem
        name="Product Specification"
        id="menu_product_specification"
        parent="base.menu_mrp_root"
        sequence="16"
        />


 <menuitem
        name="Product Pspec"
        id="menu_product_pspec"
        parent="menu_product_specification"
     action="product_specification_product_act_window"
        />


</data>
</openerp>
```

How to create the lower/marked part.

** Component part is an example i need to create that only. Upper & Menu part already done.

Answer (score 1):

**edited:**

As far as i can see, you want to create a one2many relation between pspec and pspec.details. on your details side all seems fine, but on your pspec side you need an extra one2many field as relation to your details like:

```
from openerp.osv import orm, fields

class product_pspec(orm.Model):

  _name = "product.pspec"

  _columns = {
    'prototype': fields.char('Prototype#', size=20),
    'style': fields.char('Style#', size=20),
    'customer': fields.char('Customer', size=20),
    'body_type': fields.char('Body Type', size=20),
    'program_brand': fields.char('Program/Brand', size=20),
    'color_asstmnt': fields.char('Color Asstmnt', size=200),
    'size_info': fields.integer('Size Info', size=20),
    'description': fields.char('Description', size=500),
    'designer': fields.char('Designer', size=20),
    'factory': fields.char('factory', size=20),
    'pcs_hanger': fields.integer('Pcs/Hanger', size=20),
    'developed_sold': fields.char('Developed/Sold', size=20),
    'details_ids':fields.one2many("product.pspec.details","product_pspec_id", string="Details") #new field

  }


class product_pspec_details(osv.osv):

  _name = "product.pspec.details"

  _columns = {
       'product_pspec_id' : fields.many2one('product.pspec', 'Product Pspec', required=True),
       'product_product_id' : fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product Product', required=True),
       'supplier_name': fields.char('Supplier Name', size=20),
       'style_number': fields.char('Style Number', size=20),
       'where_used': fields.char('Where Used', size=20),
       'est_yield': fields.char('Est. Yield', size=20),
       'price': fields.char('Price', size=20),
       'cost_dz': fields.char('Cost Dz', size=20),
  }
  _sql_constraints = [
        ('uniq_name', 'unique(product_product_id, supplier_name, where_used)', "Already Added"),
  ]
```

Then you have to use this new field in your view (xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="product_pspec_product">
<field name="name">product.pspec</field>
<field name="model">product.pspec</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
  <form string="Create product Specification" version="7.0">
    <group>
    <field name="prototype"/>
    <field name="style"/>
    <field name="customer"/>
    <field name="body_type"/>
    <field name="program_brand"/>
    <field name="color_asstmnt"/>
    <field name="size_info"/>
    <field name="description"/>
    <field name="designer"/>
    <field name="factory"/>
    <field name="pcs_hanger"/>
    <field name="developed_sold"/>
    <field colspan="4" name="details_ids">
        <tree string="Materials" editable="bottom">
             <field name="product_product_id"/>
             <field name="supplier_name"/>
             <field name="style_number"/>
             <field name="where_used"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
    </group>
   </form>
</field>
</record>
```

Comment: Try to do that, Error showing ...

except_orm: ('ValidateError', u'Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!')

Comment: <field name="factory"/>
    <field name="pcs_hanger"/>
    <field name="developed_sold"/>
    <field colspan="4" name="details_ids" widget="many2one_list">
        <tree string="Materials" editable="bottom">
     <field name="product_product_id"/>
     <field name="Supplier Name"/>
     <field name="Style number"/>
     <field name="Where Used"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
    </group>
   </form>
</field>
</record>

Comment: Just show you the changed part of XML. Comment can't permit full code

Comment: <field name="Supplier Name"/>
<field name="Style number"/>
<field name="Where Used"/>

you have to use your field names: supplier_name, style_number and where_used

Comment: i presume you got the new field "details_ids" in your product.pspec model. now you only need to change your xml file to (substitution for field with name="product_pspec_id":  
`<field colspan="4" name="details_ids"> 
        <tree string="Materials" editable="bottom">
     <field name="product_product_id"/>
     <field name="supplier_name"/>
     <field name="style_number"/>
    <field name="where_used"/>
        </tree> 
   </field>`

Comment: Sorry.Still It's error by Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture. I don't know why it happen. Try in various way, but output is same error.

Comment: can you post your whole stacktrace to pastebin and then link to it?

Comment: copy it from your IDE (ie Eclipse) output to http://pastebin.com/ and give me the link to it

Comment: hello Tanjil, Hope your issue solved. if not than you can ask further. But If solved than accept the answer and appreciate the help.